# Set MongoDB to Serialize a class as BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` as an insertion input for `MongoDB.Save()`.

When I fill this dictionary with primitive types - the serialization process works fine but when I'm trying to insert my dictionary filled with some custom class (for example - Person class) I'm getting the next error:
`.NET type 'Person' cannot be mapped to a BsonValue`

I noticed that if I insert my custom type converted to `BsonDocument` the serialization process work great.

How can I define MongoDB to serialize a particular class as `BsonDocument`?

---

Update: real code provided

```
    here is my SensorData class: 

    [DataContract]
    public class SensorData
    {

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Desc { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public SensorStatus Status { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string ValueUnits { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Boolean)]
        public bool Event { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [BsonElement]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
        public int TTL { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the methods which saves the data to MongoDB:

```
public void Save(Dictionary<string, object> RawSensorMessageDictionary)
        {          
            try
            {
                var policyColl = new MongoClient(ConnString).GetServer().GetDatabase(DB_NAME).GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionNames.RawSensorMessage.ToString());


                if (!RawSensorMessageDictionary.Any(p => p.Key == "_id")) //if rawSensorMessageID is empty, mongodb will set it
                    RawSensorMessageDictionary.Add("_id", ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString());
                var bsonObj = new BsonDocument(RawSensorMessageDictionary);
                policyColl.Save(bsonObj);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                   //log exception
            }
        }
```

And here is the code from my UnitTest:

```
            DataAccess.MongoDAL dal = new DataAccess.MongoDAL();
            Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dic.Add("1", true);
            dic.Add(Message.RESOURCE_TYPE, "aaa");
            dic.Add(Message.RESOURCE_NAME, "bbb");
            dic.Add(Message.SENSOR_DATA, new SensorData { Desc = "aaa", Event = true, Status = SensorStatus.Active, TTL = 4, Type = "sss", Value = "222" });
            dal.SaveRawSensorData(dic );
```

I want my app to Serialize automatically `SensorData` object to `BsonDocument`. If I don't do it manually I'm getting the following exception: `.NET type 'SensorData' cannot be mapped to a BsonValue`

How should I do it?

---

Update 2:
OK found the issue, In my "save to db" method I used the next code in order to convert my dictionary  `BsonDocument`:

```
        var bsonObj = new BsonDocument(RawSensorMessageDictionary);
```

I would expect that creating a new instance of 'BsonDocument' from other object will handle the conversion exactly like `object.ToBsonDocument()` does but apparently it's not.

Finally I replaced the code above to the following one:

```
    var bsonObj = RawSensorMessageDictionary.ToBsonDocument();
    dal.SaveRawSensorData(dic );
```

now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the string in the dictionary is the property in your mongodb document, than a non primitive type is a subdocument in mongodb. Please try to mark all properties in the class with `[BsonElement]` and the Bson Id with `[BsonId]`. And be sure you follow all rules from here: [Serialize Documents with the C# Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/)
It would be nice, if you provide some more information

**EDIT 1**
I would try to remove all properties of `SensorData` besides **Value**. If this works, i would than add all other (one by one).

Comment: One more question, should one instance of the dictionary be one document, or is every entry in the dictionary one document?

Comment: One instance of the dictionary should be represented by one document